# Using car:::linearHypothesis() with lme4 models

Tags: r, lme4, r-car

I want to test whether a coefficient (not the intercept) from a mixed effects model fit using `lme4:::lmer()` is different from a value other than zero.  `car:::linearHypothesis()` should be able to do this, with p-values and error degrees of freedom calculated using a Kenward-Rogers approximation, as implemented in `pbkrtest` (car [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf); pbkrtest [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/pbkrtest.pdf)).

However, I've run into what I think is a bug. I only seem to be able to obtain tests of the coefficient of interest against 0.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(car)
library(lme4)
library(pbkrtest)

set.seed(32432)

d <- data.frame(id=rep(1:100, 4), x=rnorm(400), y=rnorm(400))
m <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|id), data=d)

linearHypothesis(m, "x=4", test="F")
# F=.1256, p=.7232
linearHypothesis(m, "x=0", test="F")
# F=.1256, p=.7232
```

Clearly these F and p-values should not be the same!

For reference, I don't get the same bug if I use $\Chi^2$ tests, which suggests to me that the bug is `pbkrtest`:

```
linearHypothesis(m, "x=4")
# X2=5614.1, p=2.2e-16
linearHypothesis(m, "x=0")
# X2=.1268, p=.7218
```

Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Your code is the exact same for that last code chunk.

Comment: @Dason, thanks! Fixed those typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted John Fox, the author of the `car` package. He confirmed that there is indeed a bug in how `car:::linearHypothesis()` treats models fit with `lme4:::lmer()`. This should be fixed in the next version of `car`.